# WCF and ExtJS FileUpload

Tags: extjs, wcf, stream

I been trying to upload File throught WCF using ExtJS here a snippted of my code

```
  browseFile = new Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField({
  id: 'form-file',
  name: 'BrowseFile',
  fieldLabel: 'Browse',
  allowBlank: false,
  maxLength: 8000,
  emptyText: ''
```

});

added to the form and use the fileupload:true property too but havent been able to pass the byte stream into the WCF Service Layer

```
formPanel.getForm().submit(
        {
          url: 'svc/' + entityService + '/' + (isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update'),
          waitMsg: 'Please wait...',
          waitTitle: 'Submiting data',
          params:
            {
              fileData: Ext.getDom('form-file').getValue()
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate, how do you know that stream is not being passed to service? Is the error on client side or have you enabled WCF [Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731859.aspx) and/or [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx) ? If not, try those and post back any warnings and/or errors you see in diagnostics...